# Creating custom tabular-like environment

Tags: tables, environments, documentation

I want to make a custom latex environment that works like a modified tabular, that allows me to append numbers above the cell. All things made with this environment would be single-row tables.

The application in mind is to make register definitions so that I could define them simply in a manner similar to this:

```
\begin{regspec}[reg0(7:0)]{cc}
{7 6 5 4; 0.1 SEC} & {3 2 1; 0.01 SEC}
\end{regspec}
```

In this case, it would generate a register similar to that on the first line of the attached figure, but would place a name to the left, namely `reg0(7:0)`. The text within each square would be centered `{cc}`. I haven't been able to find anything that allows me to do some conditional parsing so that I can make my environment parse things like the equation environment does, but this would be ideal here.

[image: Example register definition]

Comment: TikZ can draw what you want, you just need to define lengths to use as x and y increments.

Comment: That seems like an interesting direction. I'll explore it. However, it seems like a lot more complexity, when really what I want is a simplified use of the the table that may be parameterized.